# Suggested verb/noun for "High Score"

Tags: facebook-graph-api, naming, facebook-opengraph

I'm making an arcade-type game and I want to publish the user's score to his stream. Either each time he finishes a game, or whenever he beats his own personal high score. (2 different events) But I'm looking for suggestions for the verb/noun configuration when creating my OpenGraph definitions.

[image: Facebook Open Graph - Getting Started]

I've got ideas like "**score** a **game**" and "**achieve** a **high score**", but they just seem kinda lame. Are there better suggestions or guidelines published out there anywhere?

Comment: How about synonyms for breakthrough, breakout, breakaway? annhilate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"{USER} **set** a **new personal best** in {APPLICATION}"
"{USER} is **setting** a **new personal best** in {APPLICATION}" (wouldn't really ever get called)
"{USER} and 3 other friends **set** a **new personal best** in {APPLICATION}"